# Reading GML features with shapely in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, shapely, gml

Is it possible to read GML features directly with shapely in Python?

We are able to read a GML string with GDAL to shapely via below code, but we prefer to avoid GDAL and use shapely directly:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape

geom_str = '<gml:Polygon srsDimension="3" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList count="10">207819.658 373249.741 0.0 207817.964 373252.252 0.0 207811.797 373248.147 0.0 207813.477 373245.626 0.0 207814.879 373243.523 0.0 207816.619 373240.965 0.0 207818.809 373242.423 0.0 207826.753 373247.712 0.0 207823.637 373252.39 0.0 207819.658 373249.741 0.0</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon>'
geom_shape = ogr.CreateGeometryFromGML(geom_str)
shape(json.loads(geom_shape.ExportToJson()))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any Python library that parse xml files (see [Using Python to parse an XML containing GML tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58271/using-python-to-parse-an-xml-containing-gml-tags) or [How to extract data from GML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897854/how-to-extract-data-from-gml-file) for example)

With [pygml](https://pypi.org/project/pygml/) that provides the [Geo Interface protocol](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications)

```
import pygml
geom = pygml.parse("""<gml:Polygon srsDimension="3" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList count="10">207819.658 373249.741 0.0 207817.964 373252.252 0.0 207811.797 373248.147 0.0 207813.477 373245.626 0.0 207814.879 373243.523 0.0 207816.619 373240.965 0.0 207818.809 373242.423 0.0 207826.753 373247.712 0.0 207823.637 373252.39 0.0 207819.658 373249.741 0.0</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon>""")
print(geom.__geo_interface__)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(207819.658, 373249.741), (0.0, 207817.964), (373252.252, 0.0), (207811.797, 373248.147), (0.0, 207813.477), (373245.626, 0.0), (207814.879, 373243.523), (0.0, 207816.619), (373240.965, 0.0), (207818.809, 373242.423), (0.0, 207826.753), (373247.712, 0.0), (207823.637, 373252.39), (0.0, 207819.658), (373249.741, 0.0)]], 'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992'}}}


from shapely.geometry import shape
geom_shape=  shape(geom.__geo_interface__)
print(type(geom_shape))
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
print(geom_shape)
POLYGON ((207819.658 373249.741, 0 207817.964, 373252.252 0, 207811.797 373248.147, 0 207813.477, 373245.626 0, 207814.879 373243.523, 0 207816.619, 373240.965 0, 207818.809 373242.423, 0 207826.753, 373247.712 0, 207823.637 373252.39, 0 207819.658, 373249.741 0, 207819.658 373249.741))
```

Comment: Thanks gene! Nice solution. We run Python on Snowflake, which does not have pygml available unfortunately. So a fix with shapely/fiona only would be nicer, but your fix is already nice for other people :)

Comment: fiona  can read and write GML files.

Comment: yep fiona can read gml files, but was not able to read gml string with fiona yet.